# Unsupported format: The current ad product doesn't support carousel format (#2446844)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Using Facebook API. I'm getting the following error when adding an ad creative carousel for Instagram.

Unsupported format: The current ad product doesn't support carousel format (#2446844)

[image]

Comment: i also have the same problem!  I used to recreate the ads with the images that are already used in another ad creative. I use meta APIs to create Ads. Any help would be appreciable!

Comment: Found the solution: For carousel, make sure the parameter standard_enhancements -> enroll_status is OPT_OUT in the degrees_of_freedom_spec